# Open Graph request modifier 'With'

Tags: request, facebook-opengraph

Is there any info / documentation for using the 'with' modifier when making open graph requests? ... I've looked everywhere and can't find anything.

thanks

Paul

Comment: Can you give an example of what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

The current usage to my knowledge is

```
with=location
```

This can be used for a user's [feed](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#feed), home or posts

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?with=location
https://graph.facebook.com/me/home?with=location
https://graph.facebook.com/me/posts?with=location
```

I believe it only works for users, not pages.